# Trouble Updating Observable Collection when Bound to Gridview - UWP C#

Tags: observablecollection

Observablecollection is bound to gridview in UWP project. If I try to clear and add data it fails with an error because it can only be modified on the UI thread.

I have set up service broker with SQL to notify the app when there is a change to the data. This is working correctly. However, every time I try to clear and modify the observablecollection I get an exception thrown.

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
while (dr.Read())
{
EmployeeLists.Add(new Employee { Name = dr[0].ToString(), Loc = dr[2].ToString() });
}
}
```

This is the code I'm using at first to populate the observable collection. I want to listen for changes which is working. But how do I update the changes and sync them to the observable collection?

I have tried clearing the employeelists observablecollection and then adding everything again. It seems clunky, but doesn't work anyway because It says I cannot modify from another thread. I have tried several solutions online, but I'm not that familiar with ASYNC programming. Can anyone point me in the right direction?!

Comment: ok I partially solved the problem by running the code on the UI thread using dispatcher.... however the code is overly clunky. The way I am doing it is clearing the observablecollection and then adding everything back again when there is a change in the database. There must be a better way?!

Comment: ok, getting there slowly. I can modify the objects in the observable collection one by one by using ``` var item = EmployeeLists.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == dr[0].ToString()); ``` but only way I can get the bound gridview to refresh is by unbinding and rebinding. it also takes approx. 20 seconds to refresh.... so not ideal. I will take a look at streamlining. Any tips?!